# How to get_ydata given plot in axis (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know how to extract whiskers from a boxplot

```
B = plt.boxplot(x)
min_x, max_x = [item.get_ydata()[1] for item in B['whiskers']]
```

And I know how to make subplots with different plot types

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows = 2)
ax1.hist(x)
ax2.boxplot(x)
```

But how do I extract the whiskers from the ax2 boxplot?

Comment: `B = ax2.boxplot(x)`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is of course to assign the output of `boxplot` to a variable and use it as shown in the question: `bp = ax2.boxplot(x)`. If for some reason (although I can't think of any) you can't do this, you can inspect the `lines` in your Axes: the whiskers are lines 3 and 4:

```
min_x, max_x = [ax2.lines[i].get_ydata()[0] for i in (3,4)]
```